# UIToolbar not showing

Tags: ios, keyboard, hidden, uitoolbar

I want a `UIToolbar` to show up when I click on a certain `UITextField`, but the toolbar, defined in the `@interface`, doesn't show up.
This is my code for initializing and attaching it to the text field:

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(isDone:)], nil];
toolbar.hidden = NO;
[toolbar sizeToFit];

angleField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I had used similar-looking code in another project, and it worked.
Here is the code:

```
 UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad:)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad:)],
                       nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
changes.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

where `changes` is a `UITextField`

Comment: have you got the delegate set for it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that. I used code that was pretty much the same in another project, and it worked. I can post that code, too.

Comment: I don't see an `-addSubview:` in there.

Comment: would it be `[self addSubview: toolbar]`?

Comment: It may not be self. It depends on where you are trying to add the toolbar to. Is self a View? ViewController? Do you want it to be on the Navigation controller? But you do need to add the toolbar to the subview to have it appear.

Comment: what I want to do is to have the toolbar appear with the keyboard, like how it does on the Safari app, with the "next", "previous", and "done" buttons

Comment: I see. What function is all your code inside of? As in, exactly where is `angleField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;` getting called?

Comment: my function is inside the `viewDidLoad:` method, as well as the `inputAccessoryView:` call.

Comment: Check if `angleField` is nil when you are doing this.

Comment: @ACB `angleField` is not nil, and when I log the description of `angleField.inputAccessoryView`, it gives me the memory location of a `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is it, but what I did was instead of calling `setItems:` on the toolbar, I called `setItems:animated:` and now it works...

Thank you to all who responded and took the time to try to help me.
Happy coding!